# mv command reports "X and Y are the same file", cifs filesystem

Tags: ubuntu, cifs, mv

I'm trying to get a script that will rename and move videos.  Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/"
dest="/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/"

for file in "$src"*.*; do
    newfile="${dest}$(date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S").MOV"
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

I've changed the contents of the source directory several times.  Some files it chokes on, others work fine.  I can't figure out why it's seeing certain files (all in .MOV format, imported from my iPhone) as duplicates.

Output of `mount`:

```
//GRAMNAS/Files_Apps on /mnt/Files_Apps type cifs     (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,cache=strict,username=xxxxx,uid=1208001104,forceuid,gid=1208001114,forcegid,addr=x.x.x.x,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,actimeo=1)
```

ls -li on src before script run:

```
~/.scripts$ ls -li /mnt/Files_Apps/temp/
total 697384
13238340 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin   8844047 Jul 19 21:39 IMG_5624.MOV
13238349 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  96701684 Apr 14 11:58 IMG_7355.MOV
13238366 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  98690685 Apr 17 15:06 IMG_7426.MOV
13238384 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin 100289499 May  5 14:32 IMG_7568.MOV
13238579 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  75031725 May  8 11:57 IMG_7662.MOV
13239032 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  86233885 May  9 10:13 IMG_7672.MOV
13239098 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  76930641 May  9 16:03 IMG_7687.MOV
13239466 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  78796811 May 13 13:22 IMG_7806.MOV
13240809 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  92599209 May 14 12:39 IMG_7951.MOV
```

ls -li on dest before script run:

```
~/.scripts$ ls -li /mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP\ root/
total 0
```

Script output:

```
~/.scripts$ bash -v videorename.sh
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
mv: '/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/IMG_5624.MOV' and '/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/2016-07-19 21 39 21.MOV' are the same file
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
mv: '/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/IMG_7355.MOV' and '/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/2016-04-14 11 58 26.MOV' are the same file
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
mv: '/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/IMG_7426.MOV' and '/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/2016-04-17 15 06 35.MOV' are the same file
date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S"
.
.
.
```

ls -li on src after script run:

```
~/.scripts$ ls -li /mnt/Files_Apps/temp/
total 697384
13238340 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin   8844047 Jul 19 21:39 IMG_5624.MOV
13238349 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  96701684 Apr 14 11:58 IMG_7355.MOV
13238366 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  98690685 Apr 17 15:06 IMG_7426.MOV
13238384 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin 100289499 May  5 14:32 IMG_7568.MOV
13238579 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  75031725 May  8 11:57 IMG_7662.MOV
13239032 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  86233885 May  9 10:13 IMG_7672.MOV
13239098 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  76930641 May  9 16:03 IMG_7687.MOV
13239466 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  78796811 May 13 13:22 IMG_7806.MOV
13240809 -rwxrwxrwx 1 chris linuxadmin  92599209 May 14 12:39 IMG_7951.MOV
```

ls -li on dest after script run:

```
~/.scripts$ ls -li /mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP\ root/
total 0
```

Comment: This is irrational. Are you using RedHat or a related distribution? There seem to be known problems in this area, such as [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1284993), without a current solution. I'm on Ubuntu myself, and I've never seen this message, despite frequent use of `mv`. I can't easily test if you're not using a Debian-derived system. You could try moving to a different file system and back: I feel instinctively that this may be a work-round, but I can't test, and you won't know until you try.

Comment: I'm on the latest Ubuntu

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1, and I've never seen anything like this. The only possible explanation that I can think of is that there are links of some sort (symbolic or hard) between the files or directory locations.

Comment: @cgram: (1) I edited your question.  I changed `{dest}` to `${dest}` because there’s no way you could have gotten the results you report without the `$`. (P.S. You could use `$dest` instead.  You hardly ever need the curly braces; see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/23408#286525).) Please check that you don’t have any other typos in your question. (2) Can you do `ls -li` on the source and destination directories before and after running your script, and post the output?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott...thanks for the correction, but I had the $ in my actual script...the question was just a typo...apologies.  I've done another round of tests, and updated the question with the results, along with ls -li before/after the script run.  What's interesting is that if I take the spaces out of the newfile: "newfile="$(date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").MOV"", it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, the issue revolved around how the CIFS share was mounted.  It appears that the inode was possibly being cached, thereby rendering most files duplicates as the script tried to write the new file name.  To resolve this, I added 'cache=none' to fstab and remounted the share.  I've since run through the script several times with no issues.

While I know WHAT the issue was, I'm still not entirely sure WHY it was in issue.  If anyone has insight to how this affects the CIFS mount, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

For mv complaining on "the same file", try to use `mv -n` (--no-clobber): Do not overwrite an existing file:

```
mv -n "$file" "$newfile"
```

However, "mv -n" might not work properly in older GNU versions:

```
$ mv -n ./my_file /current_dir/my_file
mv: './my_file' and '/current_dir/my_file' are the same file
```

To workaround this, check if the files have same device and inode numbers with `-ef`, before moving:

```
$ [[ ./my_file -ef /current_dir/my_file ]] || mv ./my_file /current_dir/my_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not that tedious to handle:

```
#!/bin/bash

src="/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/"
dest="/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/"

for file in "$src"*.*; do
    newfile="${dest}$(date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d %H %M %S").MOV"
    mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Tell me if it solves your problem. At least it's simpler.

Comment: That is cleaner, thanks.  However, I still get the same error: mv: '/mnt/Files_Apps/temp/IMG_8431.mov' and '/mnt/Files_Apps/TFTP root/2016-05-25 18 08 23.MOV' are the same file

Comment: Did you try to do the mv manually? If that does not work, try to create the destination file empty, then do the mv?

Comment: I just did...and it works.  It has to be the way the loop is handling spaces, I just can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: you copy-pasted my code, right?

Comment: I did copy/paste your code.  What's odd is that I'm only getting this error for one file.  If I clean out the destination dir, and only run the script on this one file, I still get the error.  And for what it's worth...the same thing happens if I change 'mv' to 'cp'.

Comment: Can you edit your question with new informations? new code, new tests. Also add the filesystem(s) you use (lsblk -f).

Comment: yarl...I've updated the original question with the current code, and a recent output.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Another caveat....if I reboot the box, then rerun the script (without changing anything in the source or dest directories), it suddenly works.  Could there be something cached that's causing this?

Comment: Can you edit your post with the relevant part of output of "mount"?

Comment: I'm assuming that's what you meant?

Comment: one more piece of info....if I remove the spaces in the new file "newfile="$(date -r "$file" +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").MOV"", it works just fine.

Comment: Yes it's what I meant. I don't know cifs enough. I can't try to help anymore.